# Calculating the shortest route around cylinder

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, vectors

If I have the following situation, what would the path look like? Where would the path go and how would I calculate it?

Cylinder with diameter $10\,\hbox{cm}$ and height $5\,\hbox{cm}$.
Use the shortest route from a point on the top edge ($A$) to a point on the 
bottom edge ($B$) diametrically opposite $A$.

I understand the following might help but how?

$\mathbf{r}(t) = a\cos(t)\mathbf{i}+ a\sin(t)\mathbf{j}+ ct\mathbf{k}$.

With the resultant formulae as follows:
\begin{cases}
x = r\cos t  \\
y = r \sin t\\
z = \frac{h\cdot t}{2\cdot \pi\cdot n},&         (0 ≤ z ≤ h)
\end{cases}

Where:
$h$ = height
$r$ = radius
$n$ = the number of complete revolutions

Note: I know 2 methods of calculating this, but I don't know how to provide a value (or an approximation). Could a value and the process be provided?

Comment: Seems like finding the shortest distance from given point to a [cycloid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid).

Comment: @TheSoundMan: Could you please clarify whether or not the cylinder is open and the path is to be taken over the curved surface of the cylinder? Or does the cylinder have flat end caps and the path is allowed to traverse those? (You've got answers for each interpretation....)

Comment: For the sake of the question, the path cannot go over the lid/cap

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question properly, open up the cylindar to form a rectangle $5{\rm{ by 20}}\pi $

A is one corner of the rectangle and B is half way along the ${\rm{20}}\pi $ side.

Using pythagoras gives a distance around the cylindar of 
$\sqrt {100\mathop \pi \nolimits^2  + \mathop 5\nolimits^2 } $

Comment: but isn't it shorter over the top of the cylinder? ie; partially around, partially over?

Comment: If you experiment with a tin can and a string you will find the shortest way is around the side, even with a very squat cylinder

Comment: @StephenP is not correct. Imagine a cylinder with zero height. Distance across is the diameter, but distance around is half the circumference - about 1 and a half times longer. As the height increases there comes a point where it is more efficient to go around the outside - I will leave that to the reader...

Comment: @tomi: The OP doesn't say so explicitly, but context strongly suggests the problem concerns a path _along the curved surface of a cylinder_, in which case this answer is perfectly correct, because a line segment gives the shortest distance between two points in a rectangle. :)

Comment: Maybe. I thought it was more like this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123022/distance-across-cylinder

Answer (score 1):

Let's label the shortest path red and then flatten the shape:
[image]
So we need to minimize the path: $$\min\limits_{\theta}\left(\sqrt{h^2+(2r\theta)^2}+2r\cos\theta\right) = 10\,\hbox{cm} \cdot\min\limits_{\theta}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\theta^2}+\cos\theta\right)=15\,\hbox{cm},$$
according to [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min+sqrt%281%2F4%2Bx%5E2%29%2Bcos%28x%29+for+0%3C%3Dx%3C%3Dpi).